# cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No backends were found

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to run a BDD test with cucumber in a Maven project.
When I try to run `BDDdemo.feature` , I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:81)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:70)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:35)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

Environments

openjdk version : 13.0.1 
Apache Maven : 3.6.3 
TestNG : 6.14.3 
cucumber : 1.2.6 
IDE : IntelJ IDEA

dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <!--<type>pom</type>-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <!--<type>pom</type>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <!--<type>pom</type>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried the all solutions in stack overflow regarding this issue. But nothing worked for me.
Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that, according to your `pom.xml` snippet, you are using **TestNG** and **Junit**. Thus, you need to add both **cucumber-testng** (it's already there) and **cucumber-junit** (it's missing) as cucumber backends. Please consider adding this other dependency entry to dependencies section on your `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

PS: *all the dependencies you listed seems to be test-scoped, so, consider add `<scope>tests</scope>` to each one of them to avoid unnecessarily adding those libraries to your final package (in case you are packaging a JAR).*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have already add `cucumber-junit`. You can see that in my pom.xml.

Comment: It worked !. I added  `<scope>tests</scope>` to each dependencies. Somehow it finally worked. Although I don't know why it  really worked.